# @Url.Action or Html.Action missing directive or assembly in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im unable to use Html.Action or @Url.Action in my razor application am I missing a directive or assembly at the top of my page. I want to add a link to the grid which holds an edit and delete buttons to it can anyone help me

```
var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn{ ColumnName = "name", Header = "Name"});

var grid = new WebGrid(db.Query("SELECT * FROM d_heirachy"));       
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle:"MyStyle",
headerStyle:"ColumnHeader",
alternatingRowStyle:"alternate-row",
columns: columns);
```

This is my webconfig

```
  <configuration>
<configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>        
      <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="StarterSite" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="StoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're either missing the `web.config` file in your views directory,  or you're missing the `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` section which defines namespaces to be included (by default) within each view.

Your views config should have the above node defining a  namespaces node which includes things like `System.Web.Mvc`. For example, my `~/Views/web.config` has the following section within `<configuration>`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: @KDM wrong config.  You should have two: one in your application folder and one in your views directory. I was speaking of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

When you created a new MVC app project you may not have noticed. there is another web.config in "Views" directory which only apply to its directory.

[image: another web.config for "Views"]

if You manually create ASP.NET web application or website You must create this web.config for "Views" directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I created a Razor(V2) app web site and in that app I didn't get a views directory. What happens now I can't use Html.ActionLink or @Url.Action what must I do

Comment: How do you create a Model for the website

Comment: using VS2010 File > new Project... > Installed templates > visual c# > Web (choose .NET Framework 4) > "ASP.NET MVC Web Application"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

You are missing include `System.Web.Mvc` in `Web.config`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I updated my package of Microsoft.AspNet.Razor and it worked!

[Manage Nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ymPA.png)
You can do it with Nuget package Console or with "Manage Nuget packages" of Visual Studio IDE tools menu option.

I dit it because I tried the previous answers and these not worked for me.

Thanks!